# is there a way to create a ens ethereum address to be readable one using cryptography?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, transactions, wallets, hd-wallets

I would like to generate address which are readable to people using cryptography and supporting ethereum transactions without problems, I don't want to use ens ethereum because I will have to pay for each address any X amount to do that.

it is possible or there is a better approach
thanks a lot.

Comment: vanity address generator does not fit because it can not be readable like https://ens.domains/ wallet.xyz or user@gmail.com for example, but thanks for your response

Comment: For now ethereum addresses have the same format: 40 hexadecimal digits.